# Html2Canvas Iteration in HTML table

Tags: laravel, jspdf, html2canvas

Good day! I have this dynamic table which data is coming from database.

```
<table class="ui table" style="margin-top: 1em;border:1" id = "tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="four wide">FirstName</th>
            <th class="four wide">LastName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($data as $name)
            <tr>
              <td>{!! $name !!} </td> 
            </tr>
        @endforeach    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want to do is get every row of table and screenshot that row using HTML2Canvas then the image will save to JSPDF. I only have this code of html2canvas which is capturing the whole table.

```
    var w = document.getElementById("tbl").offsetWidth;
    var h = document.getElementById("tbl").offsetHeight;
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("tbl"), {
      dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
      scale: 3, // Adjusts your resolution
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
        var doc = new jsPDF('P', 'px', [w, h]);
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 15, 40, w, h);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
      }
    });
```

How will I be able to do that? I have iteration from html table to javascript but keep getting error. here is the iteration code.

```
for (let row of tbl.rows) {
 for(let cell of row.cells) {
   console.log(cell.innerText)
 }
}
```

Thankyou in Advance

Comment: Can you please share in your question the error you are getting?

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to put my iteration codes to html2canvas but i have no luck. I guess some kind of logical error or syntax. I updated the question. Thankyou sir